# Real time input text filtration which allows only numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to make real time input type="text" filter which allows only numbers and dot, using javascript.
I wrote

Javascript:

```
<script>
function thirdTaskFunction(evnt) {
    evnt = evnt || window.event;
    var charCode = evnt.which ? evnt.which : evnt.keyCode;
    return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
}

function thirdTaskFunction(evt) { 
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function thirdTaskFunction() {
    var thirdInput = document.getElementById("thirdTaskInputText");
    thirdInput = thirdInput.onchange = thirdTaskFuncion;
    var valid = /^\-?\d+\.\d*$|^\-?[\d]*$/;
    var number = /\-\d+\.\d*|\-[\d]*|[\d]+\.[\d]*|[\d]+/;
    if(!valid.test(this.value)) {
        var compare = this.value.match(number);
        this.value = compare ? compare[0] : '';
    }

}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thirdTaskDIV">
    <input id="thirdTaskInputText" type="text" placeholder="Type a number" autofocus onkeypressed="return thirdTaskFunction(event);">
</div>
```

I was trying many ways, every thirdTaskFunction() method wasn't work, I was tested solution on w3schools so maybe this is reason? But I think that I dont remember about something that make it works. And I know is very similar to "HTML text input allow only numeric input" but it didnt works.. So I hope somebody show me whats pappyn here.

Comment: `onkeypressed` ???

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow only numbers in an input field is using a keypress event listener. So you'll want to select the input field and give it an event listener, like this:

```
     const inputField = document.querySelector("/*input field id here*/");
     inputField.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
       if(e.keyCode > 48 && e.keyCode < 57){
         e.preventDefault();
       }
     }
```

This function checks if the key that's pressed matches a number key, and if it doesn't, prevents the default action which in this case is printing the character to the input field.

If you have any questions, I'll do my best to answer them!

P.S. The keyCode numbers used are estimates based on memory, to get the key codes simply do a quick search on google for "ASCII key codes".

Answer (score 0):

The event code (**NOT keyCode** since the `keyCode` property is deprecated) for the dot is `Period` and the event code for the numbers 0 to 9 comes in the form `Digit0`, `Digit1` and so on.

Just use the `keydown` event listener to retrieve the event code and then use the [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if the current key has a code that includes "Digit" or "Period" and restrict input of that character if it doesn't include either of those two by using `preventDefault()` like this:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('thirdTaskInputText');

function checkKey(e) {
  if(e.code.includes("Digit") || e.code.includes("Period")) {
    console.log("valid input");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("not a number!");
  }
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey)
```

```html
<input id="thirdTaskInputText" type="text" placeholder="Type a number">
```

Without the console logs, you can further simplify the above code to a single if statement using the bang operator `!` like this:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('thirdTaskInputText');

function checkKey(e) {
  if(!(e.code.includes("Digit") || e.code.includes("Period"))) e.preventDefault();
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey)
```

```html
<input id="thirdTaskInputText" type="text" placeholder="Type a number">
```